# making a method available for anonymous user inside login authenticated controller

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have controller with url pattern /checkout/single. I have made this controller login authenticated. Inside this controller there is a method which needs to be made available for anonymous users as well. Can someone provide me with appropriate spring-security-config.xml configurations assuming the method request mapping is /test.
Here is complete configuration -

`<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" pattern="/checkout/**" use-expressions="true">
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="fixation" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout/single/test" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/> 
                <!-- SSL / AUTHENTICATED pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout/j_spring_security_check" requires-channel="https" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP')" requires-channel="https" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkout/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP')" requires-channel="https" />
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/checkout/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login/checkout" authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginCheckoutAuthenticationFailureHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginCheckoutGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.http.port')}" https="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.ssl.port')}" />
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443" />
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:request-cache ref="httpSessionRequestCache" />
</security:http>`

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, you need to write the intercept url for the anonymous user in the first line. Spring security will check first this line. Then this method will be available for anonymous, but the other methods will require login even if they are in the same controller.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/checkout/single/anotherMethod" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/checkout/single" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

Comment: I had kept it's `access="permitAll"` but it still wasn't working. Will it provide any diiferent authentication layer than `hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')`?

Comment: Your role group is different. Could you try this `<intercept-url pattern="/checkout/single/test" access="isAnonymous()"/>`

Comment: It didn't work. Still redirecting to login page. I have added the code section in my question. Please have a look and share any suggestions.